# How to trigger the execution of the compensation flow for the activities used within an Automatonymous state machine?

Tags: masstransit, saga, automatonymous

My activities throw exceptions from time to time during the execution, so I've implemented the Faulted methods of `Activity<TInstance>` to handle that, discarding the changes made in the `Execute` method. I thought that there's some wiring underneath in Automatonymous that makes it so that the Faulted method executes when the `Execute` method throws an exception and then calls the Faulted methods for the activities that were executed already. It turns out that there's no such thing, as my Faulted methods are never executed.

Should I call those myself in a try/catch block instead? I could produce the `BehaviorExceptionContextProxy` based on `BehaviorContext` and the exception thrown. The only next `Behavior` I could pass would be the one inserted into that `Activity`'s `Execute` method, but logically that means I'm compensating in the wrong direction as that next `Behavior` is actually to be executed after this one succeeds, so I'd compensate too much.

I also tried to use the `Catch` in the state machine, which does handle the exception, however, I couldn't find any way to start the execution of the compensation flow for the activity that failed when I only have the `ExceptionActivityBinder` present.

Is there any good way to trigger the compensation flow of the activities?

Comment: Automatonymous state machines are used for sagas and Activities are used for the Courier. You need to use the Courier to execute your activities and make the fallbacks to work.

Comment: Hm, that feels a bit unintuitive providing that using Activities is allowed out-of-the-box when modelling the state machine and the Faulted method has to be implemented for each and every of them.

Anyway, thanks for the information. I think I'll rewrite the compensation using the Catch methods in state machine itself.

Comment: I am not sure, maybe I am missing something but I never have seen activities being used in Automatonymous state machines.

Comment: You can add the activities to your state machine through the Activity extension method, if you want to use a factory: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.AutomatonymousIntegration/ContainerActivityExtensions.cs


Or just through the .Execute if you want to instantiate them on the spot:
https://github.com/MassTransit/Automatonymous/blob/develop/src/Automatonymous/ThenExtensions.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An activity within a state machine (using Automatonymous) is much different than an activity within Courier. Unfortunately, they both have the same name, which can create confusion.

When an activity throws an exception, the `Faulted` method of the next activity in the behavior is called. If that method is a regular activity method (such as .Then, .Publish, etc.) it is skipped, since the `Faulted` method of those activities just calls the next activity in the behavior.

A `Catch` activity, however, can be used to catch the exception and execute a rescue behavior (which is a sequence of activities).

Either way, the Faulted method of the activity which throws an exception within the Execute method is not called. So yes, you should use a try/catch, but allow the exception to flow back out of the Execute method so that the behavior handles it properly.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I expected, got a bit confused after talking to Alexey. Thanks for the answer. That explains why my activities' .Faulted were not executed. In the end in states where activities are executed I've added the Catch and publish an event with the exception details to be handled by another activity created just for exception mitigation.